# Regarding sorted data in Fast 3 Way Partition / in place quicksort via Sedgewick

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am interested in the 3 way partition in quickSort at http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/Quick3way.java.html
because it uses that partition to overcome the Dutch National Flag problem (equal data) in an in-place quicksort.
Since the author is Sedgewick I would assume that there is no error in that code, yet the pivot selected is prone to worst case n^2 time complexity for sorted data.

According to wikipedia:

> In the very early versions of quicksort, the leftmost element of the        partition would often be chosen as the pivot element. Unfortunately, this causes worst-case behavior on already sorted arrays, which is a rather common use-case. The problem was easily solved by choosing either a random index for the pivot, choosing the middle index of the partition or (especially for longer partitions) choosing the median of the first, middle and last element of the partition for the pivot (as recommended by Sedgewick).[17]

The code for the quick sort:

```
 // quicksort the subarray a[lo .. hi] using 3-way partitioning
private static void sort(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi) { 
    if (hi <= lo) return;
    int lt = lo, gt = hi;
    Comparable v = a[lo];
    int i = lo;
    while (i <= gt) {
        int cmp = a[i].compareTo(v);
        if      (cmp < 0) exch(a, lt++, i++);
        else if (cmp > 0) exch(a, i, gt--);
        else              i++;
    }

    // a[lo..lt-1] < v = a[lt..gt] < a[gt+1..hi]. 
    sort(a, lo, lt-1);
    sort(a, gt+1, hi);
    assert isSorted(a, lo, hi);
}
```

Am I correct to use the mid or ninther for the pivot or have I missed something? I realize it is instructional but why not at least use the mid?

EDIT

Is shuffling considered a rigorous way to prevent worst case over simply choosing a better pivot? Why not just change the pivot...Shuffling a large array with significant randomness would take some overhead would it not? Since a shuffle algorithm takes extra time, why not choose the pivot? Shuffling data with all equivalent data is a complete waste for instance. Would it not be better to run isSorted on the array as an heuristic with a needed edit for equiv data? –
not one to argue with Hoare, but would it not be better to check ifSorted with a modification for equiv data that would short circuit rather than run the data through the sort unnecessarily? It would take the same time as a shuffle.

Comment: Using the mid point, or the median of the first, middle, and last element (swapping as needed so that the median ends up at the middle), eliminates worst case time for sorted or reverse sorted arrays. There's a point of diminishing returns in trying to prevent worst case behavior with quicksort, in which case merge sort ends up faster. Merge sort uses a working array the same size (or 1/2 the size) as the original array, but space usually isn't an issue. With 16 registers, such as a PC in 64 bit mode, then 4-way merge sort is about as fast as quicksort, without the worst case issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sort` method you quoted is a `private` helper method. The real `public` method `sort` is like this:

```
public static void sort(Comparable[] a) {
    StdRandom.shuffle(a);
    sort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
    assert isSorted(a);
}
```

By calling `StdRandom.shuffle`, the array is randomly shuffled before doing quicksort. This is the way to protect against the worst case.

It's not only used for this 3-way partition quicksort, it's also used in the normal quicksort.

---

Quoting from the *Algorithms* book by Sedgewick, §2.3 QUICKSORT

> Q. Randomly shuffling the array seems to take a significant fraction of the total time for the sort. Is doing so really worthwhile?
>
> A. Yes. It protects against the worst case and makes the running time predictable. Hoare proposed this approach when he presented the algorithm in 1960—it is a prototypical (and among the first) randomized algorithm.

Comment: Is shuffling considered a rigorous way to prevent worst case over simply choosing a better pivot? Why not just change the pivot...Shuffling a large array with significant randomness would take some overhead would it not? Since a shuffle algorithm takes extra time, why not choose the pivot? Shuffling data with all equivalent data is a complete waste for instance. Would it not be better to run isSorted on the array as an heuristic?

Comment: not one to argue with Hoare, but would it not be better to check ifSorted with a modification for equiv data that would short circuit rather than run the data through the sort unnecessarily?It would take the same time as a shuffle.

Comment: No, it's NOT the same. The random shuffling is much more than just checking if the array is already sorted.

Comment: random shuffling of data the may already be sorted is much more than checking if it is sorted. that's a new one; perhaps you could explain....